# How to use scale in R for a precise lookback period?

Tags: r, scale, center

I would like to scale & center some data, I know how to scale it with

```
(scale(data.test[,1],center=TRUE,scale=TRUE))
```

I have 365 observations (one year), and would like to scale & center my data for a lookback period of 20 days.

For example I would like to do that:
"Normalized for a 20day lookback period" means that to scale my first value 01/01/2014 (dd/mm/yy) I have to scale it only with the 20 days before. So with values from the 11/12/13 to 31/12/13
And for the 02/01/14 scale it from the 12/12/13 to the 01/01/14 etc

Normalize the data would be
= ( the data - the mean of all data / standard deviation of all the data (see my code )

But as I want "20 day lookback period" means that I have to only look at the 20 last values it would be
= (the data - the mean of the 20 previous data) / standard deviation of the 20 previous data

I thought to make a loop maybe? As I am very new to R I don't know how to write a loop in R or even if there is a better way to do what I want...
If you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You want a 20 days lookback :  `lookback<-20` `data.scale<-c() #Create
>   a vector for the data scaled` `for(i in lookback:nrow(data)){` 
>   `mean<-mean(data[i-(lookback-1):i,1],na.rm=T)` 
>   `sd<-sd(data[i-(lookback-1):i,1],na.rm=T)*sqrt(((lookback-1))/lookback)`
>   `data.scale<-c(data.scale,(data[i,1]-mean)/sd) }`

for the row 20 you want to normalized with the data from day 1 to day 20, day 21 from day 2 to day 21 and so on...

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but sorry I explained myself very bad I am not English speaking so... I edited my post, hoping you will understand me better

Comment: for the row 20 you want to normalized with the data from day 1 to day 20, day 21 from day 2 to day 21 and so on...

`for(i in 20:nrow(data)){
mean<-mean(data[i-19:i,1],na.rm=T)
sd<-sd(data[i-19:i,1],na.rm=T)*sqr((i-1)/i)
data.scale<-c(data.scale,(data[i,1]-mean)/sd)
}`

Comment: Yes that's it exept I want for the row 21 to normalized with the data from day 1 to day 20, day 22 from day 2 to day 21 and so on... 
So would it be: `for(i in 20:nrow(data)){ mean<-mean(data[i-20:i,1],na.rm=T) sd<-sd(data[i-20:i,1],na.rm=T)*sqr((20)/21) data.scale<-c(data.scale,(data[i,1]-mean)/sd) }` ???? Besides I have this error "object 'data.scale' not found". Thanks for your help and could you edit your post with some explanation for the code, like that if I uderstand what your are doing I could maybe do it again myself next time :) thanks

Comment: You have to create a dataframe before the loop : `data.scale<-c()`

Comment: Now I have this error... : Error in data.test[i, 1] - mean : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: I cant be helpfull if you didn't show me part of your data.
Show me `head(data)` for example

Comment: I am sorry. 
> head(data.test)
        Date Sentiment 
1 01/01/2014     0.300          
2 02/01/2014     0.200          
3 03/01/2014    -0.853          
4 04/01/2014     0.000          
5 05/01/2014     0.183          
6 06/01/2014    -0.973         

Besides I am sorry it was the second column not the 1st one, I change [,1] by [,2] but have the same error : 

`for(i in 20:nrow(data.test)){ mean<-mean(data.test[(i-19):i,2],na.rm=T) +
+ sd<-sd(data.test[(i-19):i,2],na.rm=T)*sqr((i-1)/i) +
+ data.scale<-c(data.scale,(data.test[i,2]-mean)/sd) }
Error in data.test[i, 2] - mean : non-numeric...`

Comment: Try to do it manually. 
Take several rows and do the calcul in loops to see what happened.

Comment: I found how to fix my problem: I put a "+" in the code that should not be there and I replace "sqr" in your code by "sqrt". Now I have a result of 348 values.... but I don't understand as I should have only 346... (365-19=346)

Comment: Be careful a ")" is missing in your code at the first line, & a "t" to "sqrt", I ran the code that you edit (with these two modifications) and now it's working and I have 346 values !!! thank you!

Comment: Thank you i didn't run it so didn't see that. =)